# shinyapps.io does not work when my shiny use RODBC to link a SQL database

Tags: sql, r, shiny, rodbc, shinyapps

On my local computer, I use shiny to design a web page to show the analysis result. The data is extracted from the company's SQL database using RODBC to link the database to R. The code is like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(RODBC)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
DNS <- '***'
uid <- '***'
pwd <- '***'
convertMenuItem <- function(mi,tabName) {
  mi$children[[1]]$attribs['data-toggle']="tab"
  mi$children[[1]]$attribs['data-value'] = tabName
  mi
}
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    convertMenuItem(menuItem("Query1",tabName="Query1",icon=icon("table"),
                             dateRangeInput('Date1','Date Range',start = Sys.Date()-1, end = Sys.Date()-1,
                                            separator=" - ",format="dd/mm/yy"),
                             textInput('Office1','Office ID','1980'),
                             submitButton("Submit")), tabName = "Query1"),
    convertMenuItem(menuItem("Query2",tabName="Query2",icon=icon("table"),
                             dateRangeInput('Date2','Date Range',start = Sys.Date()-1, end = Sys.Date()-1,
                                            separator=" - ",format="dd/mm/yy"),
                             textInput('Office2','Office ID','1980'),
                             submitButton("Submit")), tabName = "Query2"),
  )
)
body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName="Query1",
            helpText('********************************'),
            fluidRow(
              column(12,DT::dataTableOutput('table1'))
              )
            ),
    tabItem(tabName = "Query2",h2("Widgets tab content"))
   )
)
dashboardheader <- dashboardHeader(
  title = 'LOSS PREVENTION'
) 
ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin='purple',
  dashboardheader,
  sidebar,
  body
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    ch<-odbcConnect(DNS,uid=uid,pwd=pwd)
    a <- sqlQuery(ch,paste(' ***'))
    odbcClose(ch)
    DT::datatable(a,options = list(scrollX=T))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Then, I have my account on shinyapps.io. And use rsconnect to deploy this programm. And the deployment is successful.

But when I use https://myAccount.shinyapps.io/myshiny/ to access my code. I have the following error:

```
2018-05-10T00:57:38.473259+00:00 shinyapps[340325]: Warning in RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=****;UID=****;PWD=****") :
2018-05-10T00:57:38.473262+00:00 shinyapps[340325]:   [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

But, if there is no RODBC and SQL database involved in my code, the code works fine.

So, the problem is because shinyapps.io cannot access my company's SQL database. How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app works on your computer because the Data Source Name (DSN) has been configured there. It is not configured on shinyapps.io. According to [this help article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/225408367-Connecting-to-databases-using-RODBC-on-shinyapps-io) you can use for example

```
odbcDriverConnect('Driver=FreeTDS;TDS_Version=7.0;Server=<server>;Port=<port>;Database=<db>;Uid=<uid>;Pwd=<pw>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')
```

A more complete treatment can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html#accessing-databases-with-odbc).

Comment: Thanks. I also have the issue of firewall. This whole job looks complex for me.